# Moq Setup not working, the original method is still called

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

The original method it still called when i try to use Moq. Here is my code:

```
var mockedBetRepository = new Mock<BetRepository>(new FakeSiteContext());
mockedBetRepository.CallBase = true;
Bet bet = new Bet();
mockedBetRepository.Setup<Bet>(m => m.UpdateBet(bet)).Returns(bet);

betRepository = mockedBetRepository.Object;
```

Later in the code, `betRepository.UpdateBet(bet)` is called, but its not my mocked method which gets called, instead, the class's method gets called:

```
public virtual Bet UpdateBet(Bet betToUpdate)
{
    siteContext.Entry(betToUpdate).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    siteContext.SaveChanges();
    return betToUpdate;
}
```

Why it this happening?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found the problem.

If i replace

```
Bet bet = new Bet();
mockedBetRepository.Setup<Bet>(m => m.UpdateBet(bet)).Returns(bet);
```

with this

```
mockedBetRepository.Setup<Bet>(m => m.UpdateBet(It.IsAny<Bet>())).Returns((Bet b) => b);
```

Then it works.

Comment: Are you using the same reference when you Setup the method as you do when it's actually called?  Is so that would explain the behavior you were seeing, as Moq can be used to test that specific values were used when Verifying.  For reference types, that would be specific instances of your object.

Comment: Yeah, that was probably it. Didn't know the mocks were so exclusive and explicit.

Comment: why we should use It.IsAny<Bet>() instead of writing a method.

Answer (score 0):

Your setting callbase to true, which will call your actual implementation.

Comment: Yes, it will call the base implementation "if no setups it matched", which what i can see, there is?

Comment: @ErikTJ And did you try it without CallBase = true?

Comment: I have found the solution, see my answer. Also setting CallBase = false is not possible since i need just to mock one method of many.

Comment: @ErikTJ You asked "why is this happening" and I explained why it was happening.  I wasn't suggesting you set CallBase to false.